# How can I call the method from class Z3_2 in main class?

Tags: java

```
public class Z3_2_Tester{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] tablica = {'S','O','M','E','T','E','X','T'};
        Z3_2 z = new Z3_2();


        z.Z3_2(tablica);
    }
}

class Z3_2{
    static char toUpperCase(char t)
    {
        //tablica = t;
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use spaces instead of tabs when formatting code for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `z.Z3_2(tablica);` is invalid.  You can't have a method named the same as the class name -- that's reserved for constructors.  You presumably mean `Z3_2.toUpperCase(tablica);`, but that's invalid too, because the parameter type is wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks: Your point about having a method named the same as a class is incorrect - you can in Java, it's just a *really* bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet - He's trying to call a method named the same as the class.  No such method is declared, however.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yup, spotted that afterwards, and will update my answer. But it *could* have been valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate your assistance. I'm beginer in java.

Answer (score 3):

You've got three mistakes at the moment - one is not an *error*, it's just a really bad idea. The other ones are what you're running into at the moment.

Firstly, you've got a *static* method, but you're calling it as if it were an instance method. Don't do that - it means your code doesn't do what it looks like it's doing. You should call a static method just by the class name:

```
Z3_2.toUpperCase(...);
```

The second problem is that your method is called `toUpperCase`, but you're trying to call it as if it were called `Z3_2`... that's the name of the class, not the method.

The third problem is that your method has a parameter type of `char`, but you're trying to pass in a `char[]`. You either need to change the parameter type, or call it with a single `char` at a time, e.g.

```
for (char c : tablica) {
    Z3_2.toUpperCase(c);
}
```

Additionally:

- You need to make your `toUpperCase` method return something, given that it has a return type of `char`
- You should almost certainly use the return value of `toUpperCase` in `main`
- A class name of `Z3_2` is meaningless. Names are important - choose them carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate your assistance. I'm beginer in java

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in main :

```
Z3_2.toUppeCase('s');
```

You can do this as the method is static and doesn't need an object to invoke it.

It should print

```
S
```

Second part of the problem is passing an array instead of single char.
There are 2 things you can do about it. Either call it in a loop. or make the method take in the array.

Approach 1:

```
for(Character ch: tablica){
     Z3_2.toUppeCase(ch);
}
```

Approach 2:

```
static char toUpperCase(Character[] t)
{
    for(Character ch: t){ 
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate your assistance. I'm beginer in java